# GWT Upgrade from 2.3 to 2.8.1

Tags: java, gwt-2.8

I am trying to upgrade my java web application from 2.3 to 2.8.1. Following are my jars in Pom xml:

```
antlr-3.1.1.jar 
aopalliance-1.0.jar          
aspectjweaver-1.5.2.jar 
commons-cli-1.1y.jar 
commons-codec-1.10.jar 
commons-collection-3.2.1.jar 
commons-configuration-1.9.jar 
commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar 
commons-discovery-0.2.jar 
commons-el-1.0.jar 
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar 
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar 
commons-io-1.3.1.jar 
commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar 
commons-jxpath-1.3.jar 
commons-Lang-2.6.jar 
commons-lang3-3.5.jar 
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar 
commons-modeler-2.0.1.jar 
commons-pool-1.4.jar 
commons-vfs-1.0.jar 
dom4j-1.6.1.jar 
ehcache-core-2.5.0.jar 
ews-java-api-2.0.jar 
gwt-log-3.1.3-redhat-2.jar 
gwt-servlet-2.8.1.jar 
gwtupload-0.6.3-compat.jar 
gwt-user-2.8.1.jar 
gwt-visualization-1.1.1.jar 
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar 
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar 
hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar 
httpclient-4.4.1.jar 
httpcore-4.4.1.jar 
itext-2.1.5.jar 
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar 
jdom-1.1.jar 
jersey-client-1.9.1.jar 
jersey-core-1.9.1.jar 
jettison-1.2.jar 
joda-time-2.0.jar 
json-20080701.jar 
jxl-2.6.8.jar 
kxml2-2.3.0.jar 
kxml2-min-2.3.0.jar 
log4j-1.2.16.jar 
logback-core-0.6.jar 
lucene-core-2.4.1.jar 
ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar 
spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar 
spring-aspects-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar 
spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar 
spring-context-support -4.3.18.RELEASE.jar 
spring-context -4.3.18.RELEASE.jar 
spring-core -4.3.18.RELEASE.jar 
spring-expression -4.3.18.RELEASE.jar 
spring-instrument -4.3.18.RELEASE.jar 
spring-jdbc -4.3.18.RELEASE.jar 
spring-jms -4.3.18.RELEASE.jar 
spring-orm -4.3.18.RELEASE.jar 
spring-oxm -4.3.18.RELEASE.jar 
spring-test -4.3.18.RELEASE.jar 
spring-tx -4.3.18.RELEASE.jar 
poi-3.9.jar 
poi-examples-3.9.jar 
poi-excelant-3.9.jar 
poi-ooxml-3.9.jar 
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar 
poi-scratchpad-3.9.jar 
saaj-api-1.3.jar 
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar 
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar 
smartgwt-3.0.jar 
smartgwt-skins-3.0.jar 
stax-1.2.0.jar 
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar 
groovy-swing-2.4.7.jar 
velocity-1.6.1.jar 
wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar 
wstx-asl-3.2.7.jar 
xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar 
xstream-1.4.6.jar 
jcifs-1.3.17.jar 
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar 
dhbcore-dhbcore.jar 
com.ibm.mq-8.0.0.5.jar 
com.ibm.mq.headers-8.0.0.5.jar 
com.ibm.mq.jmqi-8.0.0.5.jar 
com.ibm.mq.pcf-8.0.0.5.jar 
com.ibm.mqjms-8.0.0.5.jar 
com.ibm.mq.connector-7.5.0.5.jar 
dhbcore-7.5.0.5.jar 
mqcontext-2.3.jar 
com.ibm.mq.commonservices-8.0.0.5.jar 
isc-jakarta-oro-2.0.6.jar 
isomorphic_applets-isomorphic_applets.jar 
isomorphic_core_rpc-isomorphic_core_rpc.jar 
isomorphic_sql-isomorphic_sql.jar 
isomorphic_web_services-isomorphic_web_services.jar 
mail-1.4.6.jar 
jta-1.1.jar 

gwt-maven-plugin-2.8.1
```

when I run the application from eclipse using “mvn gwt:run-codeserver”, it says http://127.0.0.1:9876 started and ready. But I see some errors before that:

```
Tracing compile failure path for type ‘...’: ERROR Line xxx: No source code is available for type org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I see several of them like above in the console. When I run http://127.0.0.1:9876 I see: GWT Code Server

1. Drag these two bookmarklets to your browser’s bookmark bar: Dev Mode On Dev Mode Off
2. Visit a web page that uses one of these modules: <MY_MODULE>

When I click on my module, I see “this module hasn’t been compiled yet”. Please advise.

Comment: I assume the application was working with GWT 2.3?

Comment: Yes. It works fine with GWT 2.3.